# How does the temperature of HCl affect the reaction rate of HCl & Mg reaction?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, temperature, reaction-control

I'm Olivia. I'm experimenting with HCl and Mg. My purpose is to find the change of the reaction rate while I increase the temperature of HCi.

According to the study, when I increase the temperature of the reactant, the time of the reaction should be shorter, which means that the reaction rate should be higher.

However, when I was in the lab, I met a problem. When I increase the temperature of HCl, the time it took for Mg to dissolve in HCl became longer.

I put 0.1g of Mg into 50ml of HCl and repeat that 4 times. I heat the HCl to 20, 40, 60, and 80 degrees Celsius in 4 separate beakers. Then, I put 0.1g of Mg into it, and the time it took to dissolve completely was 22, 25, 29 and 29 seconds.

I'm pretty sure that I weigh and measure the Mg and HCl properly; the size of a piece of Mg is also the same, which means that the surface area should be the same.

I'm truly confused right now because observations are completely different from what I learned. Is this one a special case, or if there was something that I might have done incorrectly?

Thank you for your time to look at my questions and provide a valuable answer.

Comment: You have chosen a very complicated system, being an inter-phase heterogenic reaction. As the effective reaction rate is not determined solely by the reaction kinetic, but also by the contact surface. transient layer thickness and properties, rate of diffusion of reactants and products and variable local concentrations.

Comment: .... as the result, while the reaction rate at the same "reactant meeting rate" would increase with temperature, the effective reaction rate can decrease, as  the  "reactant meeting rate" may be decreased. If considering the Arrhenius equation for thje reaction rate, while the exponential factor would increase, the frequency factor may decrease even more.